# Why some old manufacturer notebook can be overclocked but not modern one?

Tags: overclocking

Back to the old days, when Pentium M or Atom N450 were the mainstream notebook/netbook processor, most of these notebook were able to manually overclock with some famous software like SetFSB even there the BIOS doesn't have overclock option to play with. However, nowaday most of the notebook can't be manually overclocked.

My curious is:

1. Why a software can interrupt a hardware this way even it is not configurable in BIOS?
2. Why this type of software overclocking is no longer exist for modern notebook?

Comment: I believe this to be as when the older notebook/netbooks were made they did not go into further overclocking or run the chips the best they could probably due to saving battery and various other things. These days the Manufacturer Tries to Clock it as best as they can for Notebooks that come with a standard processor not make to be overclocked. Not putting this as an answer as its just my idea on the situation.

Comment: This is totally off-topic here but in my view that's due to marketing. The "old" Pentium M and Atom CPUs were an initial step to reduce power consumption significantly, and had very poor performance. Today, with the adaptive frequency scaling and a better performance per Watt, you can actually _sell_ overclocking features to the customers since the starting point is satisfactory.